# バッチファイルで、 bash でいうところの -e 指定のようなことはできますか

Tags: batch-file

ウィンドウズのバッチファイルにおいて、 bash でいうところの -e オプション指定の動作を行うことは可能でしょうか。

具体的には、バッチ内で実行した各コマンドに対して exit code が 0 でないものがあった場合には、基本的にはその時点でバッチを abort させたい、というのが、やりたいことです。

もし、そんなものなどない、という場合には、上記のようなことがやりたい場合には、どのようにバッチファイルを記述するのでしょうか。各コマンドの後ろに %ERRORLEVEL% 判定を実行するしかないのでしょうか。

Comment: [How do I make a batch file terminate upon encountering an error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734598/how-do-i-make-a-batch-file-terminate-upon-encountering-an-error)

Comment: 無理矢理try-catchをバッチに実装する話。[Does Windows batch support exception handling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445330/does-windows-batch-support-exception-handling)